# segfault - c_void_p to c_byte array

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I have a simple c function that returns a bytes array and the array length:

```c
// base58.h
/* Return type for Decode */
struct Decode_return {
    void* r0;
    int r1;
};

// Decode decodes a modified base58 string to a byte slice, using BTCAlphabet
extern struct Decode_return Decode(char* p0);
```

I'm trying to call this c function from python as such:

```
// base58.py
from ctypes import *
base58 = CDLL('./base58.so')

class DecodeResponse(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("r0", c_void_p),
        ("r1", c_int),
    ]

base58.Decode.restype = DecodeResponse

expect = bytes.fromhex("61")
print(expect.decode("utf-8"))

res = base58.Decode(c_char_p("2g".encode('utf-8')))

length = c_int(res.r1).value
print(length)

ArrayType = c_byte*(length)
pa = cast(c_void_p(res.r1), POINTER(ArrayType))

print(pa.contents[:])
```

I get a seg fault when I run this, though. Why is pa.contents not addressable?

```bash
$ python3 base58.py
a
1
[1]    21864 segmentation fault (core dumped)  python3 base58.py
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understant this correctly, this casts an int to a pointer.

`pa = cast(c_void_p(res.r1), POINTER(ArrayType))`

I guess you want to replace `r1` by `r0`. I suggest to use a better naming scheme.

Comment: OMG, I dealt with this problem for hours and it was a typo... Ty so much hahaha